# When I click in my newsletter subscribe button in my footer Im going to the top of my page

Tags: php, html

When I click in my newsletter subscribe button in my footer Im going to the top of my page.

I can have my sucess message my error messages but Im going always to the top of my page. And I dont want this because I want that usre see the feedback message without scroll down to my footer.

Do you see why this happening and how can I fix this?

```
<form action="" name="newsletter" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="email_newsletter_container">
        <input type="text" id="email" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email'])) echo $email; ?>" name="email" placeholder="Insert your email..." required/>
        <input type="hidden" name="newsl_sub" value="subscribe" />
        <button class="btnn" type="submit" name="subscribe"><span>Subscribe</span></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Read a little about AJAX. ;)

Comment: Unless you have some JavaScript executing an AJAX call, your form is simply being submitted and the page reloading, which would default to the top of the page.

Comment: You'll probably want to use some sort of AJAX call with your form post

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But there isnt any method without ajax to fix this? Because with Ajax I need to change all my code!

Comment: Use an anchor link to have the page reload on the footer.

Answer (score 1):

When you put `action=""` the action will reload the page. If you put `action="#newsletter"` it should take the user to the section of the page that contains the form when the form is submitted. You may also want to add `id="newsletter"` to the form to ensure compatibilities.

Comment: Thanks Greg. But with your solution now Im getting in my url this: http://localhost/site/#newsletter. Do you know how can I prevent this?

Comment: You would have to implement a different solution using Javascript. URLs like that and Javascript are the only two ways I can think of to scroll on a webpage.

Comment: @Marby if you dont want to change url, use ajax call instead of form submission.

Answer (score 0):

```
<? if($post_was_submitted_and_comment_was_inserted) { ?> 
<script> 
window.addEventListener("load", function(){ 
document.getElementById("comments").scrollIntoView(); 
}); 
</script> 
<? } ?>
```